# PHP preg_replace doesn't work without hardcode

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-replace

When I receive an email, I would like to save just a part of this email in database, so, I use a regex to remove the part I don't want. But, this doesn't work.

```
function emailToMessage($inbox, $emails){
$messages = [];

foreach ($emails as $email_number){

    # $overview contient les infos du mail
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $headerInfos = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);
    $mailHeader = imap_fetchheader($inbox,$email_number);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);
    $subject = (isset($overview[0]->subject)) ?$overview[0]->subject : 'Pas de sujet';
    $sender = $headerInfos->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $headerInfos->from[0]->host;
    $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);

    $body = checkSubtype($structure, $body); // decode if the transfert encoding is base64 and change encoding to utf8
    $text = cleanMail($body, $mailHeader);

    #conversion de udate en format pouvant etre inséré dans mySql
    $mailDateAndTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $overview[0]->udate);

    $message = [
        'title'     => $subject,
        'text'      => $text,
        'id_sender' => $sender,
        'mailDateAndTime' => $mailDateAndTime,
    ];

    $messages[] = $message;
    }
return $messages;
}

function cleanMail($text, $mailHeader){
    $clientMail = checkMailClient($mailHeader);

switch($clientMail){
    case "gmail":
    echo($text . "<br>");
    $gmail = preg_replace("/\s+[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s+GMT\+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s+(.)*\s+:(?:\s(.)*)*/i", '$1', $text);
    echo($gmail . "<br>");
    return $gmail;
    break;
```

If

```
$body = "test

2017-09-11 11:55 GMT+02:00 XXX :

> frgthyjuki";
```

echo($text); and echo($gmail); both give me :

> test
>
> 2017-09-11 11:55 GMT+02:00 XXX :
>
> > frgthyjuki

But, if I declare $text in emailToMessage() (between the line $body = checkSubtype($structure, $body); and $text = cleanMail($body, $mailHeader);) or in cleanMail(), it works.

```
switch($clientMail){
    $text = "test

2017-09-11 11:55 GMT+02:00 XXX :

> frgthyjuki";

    case "gmail":
    echo($text . "<br>");
    $gmail = preg_replace("/\s+[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s+GMT\+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s+(.)*\s+:(?:\s(.)*)*/i", '$1', $text);
    echo($gmail . "<br>");
    return $gmail;
    break;
```

echo($text); will give

> test
>
> 2017-09-11 11:55 GMT+02:00 XXX :
>
> > frgthyjuki

and echo($gmail); will give :

> test

Why is it work only when the variable is hardcode ? What can I do settle it ?

**UPDATE**

```
function checkSubtype($structure, $body){
    $subtype = strtolower($structure->subtype);

    if($subtype == "alternative") {
        $encoding = $structure->parts[0]->parameters[0]->value;
        $encoding = strtolower($encoding);
        $transferEncoding = $structure->parts[0]->encoding;

        $body = checkIfBase64($body, $transferEncoding);
        $body = quoted_printable_decode($body);
        $body = changeToUTF8($body, $encoding);
    } else {
        $transferEncoding = $structure->encoding;
        $body = checkIfBase64($body, $transferEncoding);
    }
    return $body;
}
```

-

```
function checkIfBase64($text, $transferEncoding){
    if($transferEncoding == "3"){
        $text = base64_decode($text);
    }
    return $text;
}

function changeToUTF8($text, $encoding){
    if($encoding != "utf-8" && $encoding != 'utf8'){
    $text = utf8_encode($text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tested with Thunderbird and Orange.

I doesn't work with Thunderbird (I check my RegEx online, it's correct) but it works with Orange.

```
case "orange":
return preg_replace("/s*>(?:\s(?:.)*)*/i", '$1', $text);
break;
```

I realy don't understand...

**UPDATE 3**

I retry without the horrible solution and it works with the previous code. 
It's weird...

Comment: check that base64 thing is returning your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a horrible solution but it works...

```
case "gmail":
    $step1 = preg_replace("/\s+/i", '#', $text);
    $step2 = preg_replace("/#*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}#+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}#+GMT\+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}#+(.)*#*:(?:#(.)*)*/i", '$2', $step1);
    return preg_replace("/#/i", ' ', $step2);
    break;
```